# OSGB - number of tiles per file

Tags: openscenegraph, photogrammetry

I have OSGB models that are created with either software: AgiSoft, Bentley, SkylineSoft, Pix4D. Currently each tile in the output folder is divided into at least two files, one osgb and one or several texture file (jpg).

I have a problem in the deployment with the number of output files, in large models it can reach millions of files and when I copy them to the target computer it takes a long time. Is it possible to export with the above softwares to an osgb format that one file can contain several tiles / textures?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked this - http://osiris.itabc.cnr.it/scenebaker/index.php/projects/osglab/ ? It has APIs that exactly solve the problem you mentioned